# Can I pull 2 date fields from 1 list into a Calendar view

Tags: calendar, date

I have 1 List that has 2 separate date fields that I need to be able to pull into 1 calendar view.

How can I do this??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @SheryIT If one of the answers solved the problem stated in your question, you should **mark** & **upvote** it as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to show your list item twice, once for each date range (like planning phase, execution phase), then Calendar Overlays may be your quickest answer.  Here's an older MS page for [adding an exchange calendar](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overlay-a-SharePoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-Exchange-or-SharePoint-4caebe59-3994-4a94-9322-b31abb8a5e9a).  They share some of the same steps, but here's some quick steps for adding the SharePoint Calendar.

- Create 2 Calendar Views on your list, one using each set of dates.
- ***Optional:*** Create a 3rd "Roll-up" Calendar View, make it empty by filtering on ID = 0.  This is only to keep the other views "pure" so that your planning phase view doesn't contain execution dates.
- Browse to your roll-up view and, on the ribbon, select "Calendar" -> "Calendar Overlays".
- Click "Add Calendar" just above the empty list of calendars displayed.
- Fill in the form. Be sure to hit the "Resolve" button to populate the List drop-down, its an easy step to miss.
- Repeat the last 2 steps for the second calendar view; hit OK and you'll see both phases color coded on the same calendar.  (you did select different color options didn't you).

You can now include this view on a web part page.
  Use CSS rules for .ms-acal-apanel[0-9] to change coloring, or add calculated columns to use different event labels (Planning: Project1 vs. Executing: Project1) if [WCAG 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) compliance (color blindness) is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated column that generates a date based on your date fields. Then you can use that calculated column in Calendar view.